# Send asynchronous request without waiting the response using guzzle

Tags: php, asynchronous, guzzle, guzzle6

I have the following two functions

```
public function myEndpoint(){
    $this->logger->debug('Started');
    $this->guzzle->requestAsync('post', 'http://myurl.com/doNotWait')->wait();
    $this->logger->debug("I shouldn't wait");
}

public function doNotWait(){
    sleep(10);
    $this->logger->debug("You shouldn't wait");
}
```

Now what I need to see in my logs is:

```
Started
I shouldn't wait
You shouldn't wait
```

But what I see

```
Started
You shouldn't wait
I shouldn't wait
```

Also I tried using the following ways:

**Way #1**

```
public function myEndpoint(){
    $this->logger->debug('Started');
    $this->guzzle->requestAsync('post', 'http://myurl.com/doNotWait', ['synchronous' => false])->wait();
    $this->logger->debug("I shouldn't wait");
}
```

**Way #2**

```
public function myEndpoint(){
    $this->logger->debug('Started');
    $this->guzzle->requestAsync('post', 'http://myurl.com/doNotWait');

    $queue = \GuzzleHttp\Promise\queue()->run();
    $this->logger->debug("I shouldn't wait");
}
```

But the result is never the desired one. Any idea? I am using Guzzle 6.x.

Comment: I got an answer here https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/1429#issuecomment-197119452

Comment: Please answer your own question with what worked for you, and accept it as the correct answer to help others.

Comment: better use rabbit mq

Comment: @gmponos The answer https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/1429#issuecomment-197152914 uses https://github.com/WyriHaximus/react-guzzle-psr7 which is now deleted. Can you answer your question with a Guzzle 7 versions? I've been looking for working async code for days.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To get it off the unanswered list:

---

Guzzle does not support "fire and forget" asynchronous requests without deep hacking.

The async methods are abstractions for `Client::requestAsync()`, which returns a promise. See https://github.com/guzzle/promises#synchronous-wait - calling `Promise::wait()` "is used to synchronously force a promise to complete".

Reference: https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/1429#issuecomment-197119452

Comment: last part of the title is "using guzzle"

Answer (score 8):

If you don't care about the response, the following should do:

```
try {
    $this->guzzle->post('http://myurl.com/doNotWait', ['timeout' => 1]);
} catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException $e) {
    // do nothing, the timeout exception is intended
}
```

So, here the request will take 1 sec and the code execution will continue.

Comment: This is great. I tried with GET and tried to construct a recursion, which might be useful as some kind of cron alternative. I had to also set 'connect_timeout' and 'read_timeout' though. And once a process was stuck, I had to restart the web server. The thing seems a bit fragile if you use very small wait times, e.g. with 0.001 it did not work. But some problems might have been caused by xdebug, which I needed to check what his happening.

Comment: launch exception with error "Operation timed out after 1004 milliseconds with 0 bytes received"

Answer (score 0):

Since others wrote, that Guzzle doesn't offer a build in solution for this, here is a solution as one liner:

```
$url = escapeshellarg("http://myurl.com/doNotWait");
exec("wget -O /dev/null -o /dev/null " . $url . " --background")
```

It uses exec (https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.exec.php) to run the commandline tool `wget` (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget - its included in most linux distries and also works in Windows and OSX) command. I have tested it only on linux, so maybe the params have to be adjusted for your OS.

Lets split it up into parts

- `-O /dev/null`: The result of the request should be send to null (nowhere)
- `-o /dev/null`: The logs should be send to null
- `$url`: The url you wanna call, for example `http://myurl.com/doNotWait`
- `--background`: Run in background, do not wait.

For those who think "exec" is evil: If the params are from an user input, you could be right. If the url is defined by your code, then its not.

Comment: Working for me. I don't know why did this answer got down voted

Comment: Probably because it's not using guzzle and even php and is using exec function which is not a good idea.

Comment: The question mentioned guzzle, but doesn't say "only guzzle related answers allowed".  Using `exec` isn't the preferred way doing things, but as long there is no (unfiltered) user input involved and the rights of the user of the running scripts are correct, it is a valid fallback strategy.

Comment: You should be wrapping `$url` in `escapeshellarg()` for safety. — @benhardh Best if you could please update the answer, too.

Comment: Have added it now.

Answer (score 0):

Make asynchronous call to create promise then call then() method with no callbacks

```
$client = new GuzzleClient();
$promise = $client->getAsync($url)
$promise->then();
```

Answer (score -2):

As request *fire and forget*. One of the solutions worked for me.

```
 $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['timeout' => 0.001]);        
 $promise = $client->requestAsync('GET', 'http://dummy.site');

 try {
        $promise->wait();
 } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        ## Handle                       
 }
```

If `$promise->wait();` is not called the request was not performed.